# How to build static and shared library with autotools?

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, autotools, automake, libtool

I'm learning use the Autotools. I am writing my first program with these tools, but I havve a problem. I am trying to make program that uses two libraries: one static and one shared. I configured `Makefile.am` and `configure.ac`, but I don't know whether they are as they should be. When I run command `make`, it returns an error:

> ```
> code.c:37: undefined reference to `function1'.
> ```

It gives such an error for every function.  It seems that the program can't find headers or source files?

All my files are in one folder.

### configure.ac

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([code], [1.0])
LT_INIT
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([code.c])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])
AC_PROG_CC 
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([stdio.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

### Makefile.am

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4

bin_PROGRAMS = code
code_SOURCES = code.c libcodes.la libcode.a libo.h libp.h

lib_LIBRARIES = libcode.a
libcode_a_SOURCES = functionsp.c

code_DEPENDENCIES = libcodes.la
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libcodes.la
libcodes_la_SOURCES = functionso.c
libcodes_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info 1:0:0
code_LDFLAGS = -rpath /usr/local/lib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems that the program can't find headers or source files?

No, "undefined reference" is a link error.  It means that the linker is trying to resolve a function call, but it doesn't see any implementation of the function.  This usually implicates a problem with the libraries specified on the link command line.

And indeed, the link-related settings in your `Makefile.am` are all wrong, and there are other, less-impactful issues, too.

First, the libraries needed for linking a program but not located via `configure` should be specified in `Makefile.am` via the `LDADD` variable or a program-specific `foo_LDADD` variable.  A `foo_DEPENDENCIES` variable does not serve this purpose -- its contents appear in the generated makefile as dependencies of the program target, but nowhere else.  In particular, they are not included on the link command line.  In practice, `foo_DEPENDENCIES` variables are rarely used.

Libraries especially should not be specified as program sources.  They aren't sources, and specifying them as such has no useful effect.

Speaking of libraries, hardcoding an assumed library installation directory into your `Makefile.am` is poor form and setting yourself up for problems, as that directory can be specified by the user at `configure` and / or `make` time. Fortunately, each configurable installation directory has a corresponding variable the you can reference.  In the case of the `lib` it is `libdir`.

Also, as a matter of style, you seem to have organized your `Makefile.am` around build stages, but that is unusual, and I, at least, find it difficult to follow.  `Makefile.am` files are more often organized around the targets named, often with all those targets specified first.

Overall, then, you probably want something more like this:

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4

bin_PROGRAMS = code
lib_LIBRARIES = libcode.a
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libcodes.la

code_SOURCES = code.c libo.h libp.h
code_LDFLAGS = -rpath $(libdir)
code_LDADD = libcodes.la libcode.a
# or LDADD = libcodes.la libcode.a

libcode_a_SOURCES = functionsp.c

libcodes_la_SOURCES = functionso.c
libcodes_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info 1:0:0
```

Comment: It works! Thank for help and a lot of useful information.

Comment: I am glad to help, @crocodile2221. It is customary that when their question has been answered to their satisfaction, the OP "accepts" one of the answers by clicking the check mark next to its score.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't know about it, but already do it.